# Installing Poster(Streaming HTTP uploads and multipart/form-data encoding)

Tags: python

I've been searching the net for instructions on how to install Poster(Streaming HTTP uploads and multipart/form-data encoding) for various OSes (especially Ubuntu and Windows).The official website http://atlee.ca/software/poster/ has awesome sample scripts and examples but nothing on how to install the module on various OSes. Appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite simple, you can use easy_install or pip, in your terminal run:

```
easy_install poster
```

or

```
pip install poster
```

If you don't have easy_install or pip, install distribute first:

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
python distribute_setup.py
```

I recommend using pip and reading the excellent [documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html). You might also benefit from reading the python documentation about [distributing modules](http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html).

In the future [search pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=poster&submit=search). If it's on pypi you can pip or easy_install it.

Comment: Thanks zeekay, it works extremely well, appreciated your help.